# Flask-SLQAlchemy OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to databases, therefore sorry if this is too basic, but I had no luck with other related questions in SO.

**MODELS.py**

```
import json

from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__='user'
    """
    Model for storing user data. 
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name, username, email, address):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.address = address

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.user)
```

When I run `app.py`, an empty `player.sqlite3` is created.

**APP.py**

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, g, render_template, request, session, abort, url_for
from flask import stream_with_context, Response
from flask_mail import Mail,  Message
from flask_oauth import OAuth
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app.datafoo.db.models import *


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI= "sqlite:///%s" % os.path.join(app.root_path, 'app/datafoo/db/data/player.sqlite3'),
    DEBUG=True)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def do_admin_login():

    # check user password
    if request.form['username'] == 'john':
        session['logged_in'] = True

        db.create_all()
        u = User(name=request.form['user'], 
                 username=request.form['username'], 
                 email=request.form['email'],
                 address=None)
        db.session.add(u)
        db.session.commit()  

    else:
        flash('wrong password!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True, port=PORT, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

But I am getting the traceback:

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user [SQL: u'INSERT INTO user (name, username, email, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'John', u'johnsusername', u'john@mac.com', None)]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, how could you execute your app? You haven't even imported `User` in `APP.py`.

Comment: sorry I had forgotten to insert the import line at the question, now present. Error happens with import. I'm naive, but not THAT naive.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the table exists via another tool such as DB Browser for SQLite? https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: no I haven't tried that.